Unexpected Store Exception frequently occuring
I am running Windows 10 on Dell Vostro with upgraded 12 gb ram ,256gb ssd and 1 TB original Hard disk. My OS is installed in SSD.
Recently I have been encountering unexpected storage exception frequently.

Crystal disk info gives the following status:

Is this issue related to HDD or SSD ? My OS is installed in SSD so there shouldn't be an issue if hdd is failing. I currently have no option to replace either of these as I am in college.

Crystal disk shows you that your HDD is dying: it already has 289 defect sectors. A defect sector count of greater than zero (and may be even increasing over time) is a strong hint that your drive will most likely fail very soon. If you don't have a backup try to copy the data to a new disk starting with the files of highest value to you.

@Robert So the BSOD is caused by HDD right?

That would be likely, but other sources are also possible. But now your first action should  be replacing the HDD. You may already have lost data in the sectors that are already defect...
